# Awaiting an LoR request response

Tags: recommendation-letter

So, I have emailed my professor to ask if he felt comfortable with writing me an LoR during the weekend. I got an automated response stating that he won’t be back till this  Monday, it’s currently Wednesday and Tuesday was a state holiday. I know he just got back, has young children, and his research going on, but the wait is making me anxious. What I am asking is whether or not this is a no, maybe he’s avoiding me? I only doubt his agreement to writing me one because I got a B- in his class, and only have talked to him a few times during office hours. However I will be in another’s lecture of his next semester, and he’s approved me to be a lab course intern next semester as well. What are your opinions? Could it be that I don’t have a strong enough relationship for him to write me an LoR? Thanks in advance!

Comment: He may have several (tens or hundreds) emails in his in-box to deal with. Patience is a virtue.

Comment: Go see him. Don't depend on email for anything requiring a personal response.

Answer (score 2):

You only got a B- in his class and only talked to him a couple of times during office hours.  You sent mail over the weekend just before a two-day holiday and got an automated response that he was out of town.  It's
 the first day back and you're already worried that he hasn't responded.

In both cases, your expectations are unreasonable.  You didn't do very well in his class and he hardly knows you.  What exactly do you expect him to say that could possibly help your chances of admission anywhere?  He can't just make stuff up, he can only report what he actually knows about you, which is that your performance wasn't that good.  You need to request references from instructors who gave you A's, not B-'s.  And pick people who actually got to know you because you showed up at their office more than just a couple of times and for more than just help on the homework.

When you do ask, allow them time to respond.  Give them at least a week (longer if it's a holiday!) to say yes or no, and then at least a month (more is better!) to write the letter.  (Be sure to tell them the deadline and how the letter has to be submitted.)

You should also provide a set of materials to help your reference write a good letter. It should include a list of schools where you’re applying, copies of your transcript, resume or CV, statement of purpose, and a short reminder of who you are, e.g., the class you took from them, where you used to sit, why they might remember your work or some discussions you had, perhaps a photograph. It’s okay (and helpful) to suggest strengths you hope your reference can speak to, e.g., your creativity, ability for abstract thought, contributions to a group.

Depending on the privacy laws in your country, you may also need to state explicitly, "You have my permission to discuss my academic performance."  For example, here in the US, instructors are prohibited by FERPA from discussing a student's performance without explicit permission.

Comment: I'm curious about your last point. I've never given a professor explicit permission to write me a LoR. Have your universities told you that, as a professor, you needed it?

Comment: @AzorAhai  FERPA is pretty clear, so I already knew this.  But yes, it's come up in faculty meetings here at UMich.  The fact someone asks for an LOR isn't sufficient even though common sense would tell you that they have to expect you'll talk about their academic record.  You need explicit permission.

Comment: Huh. Guess none of the professors that ever wrote me one didn't know that. I was wondering because I knew you used to be faculty at UWB and I was in the same system and wasn't asked. Ty!

Comment: @AzorAhai When I was at UWB, I knew to ask and always did but I was probably one of the few.  All instructors here in the US should know about FERPA and should be aware of the need for confidentiality and that you can't disclose grades to third parties without permission.  But if no one points out that FERPA also applies to recommendations, it probably doesn't occur to them.

Comment: @AzorAhai, Googling turns up lots of universities advising faculty to get permission to discuss grades before writing an LOR.  Here's an example from [Penn State](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/writingrecommendationlettersonline/node/116).